# In MySQL created scheme insert value in the table with restriction based on another table type

Tags: mysql, triggers

can you please help me to resolve next problem:
I have one main table (Vehicles) and four dependent tables (different types of vehicles: passenger_car, mini_bus ... etc). (i will provide for you just for example only two of them: main and one dependent (passenger_car), because the rest of them are the similar structure, only are differ types).
[my sql schema example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSEbT.jpg)

In main table (vehicle) there will be common fields for all of vehicles types, and the part that is different will be stored in dependent tables (for Passenger car in passenger_car, for Mini Bus in mini_bus etc). I will need to write trigger for insert and update operation for passenger_car table to restrict input  in vehicle_id (foreign key) id from table (vehicles) which are relate to record with vehicle_type value is not equal to dependent table type of vehicle.

for example:
vehicle table

| id | vehicle_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | passenger_car |
| 2 | mini_buss |

passenger_car table

| id | vehicle_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 (<- is allowed) |
| 2 | 2 (<- NOT allowed!!!) |

mini_bus table

| id | vehicle_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 (<- NOT allowed!!!) |
| 2 | 2 (<- is allowed) |

Can you please help me to write such a trigger, because my knowledge of SQL is not good enough at a moment.

I tried to read documentation in MySQL and search for same problem in stackoverflow but anyway i don`t understand how to write correct trigger expression.

Comment: Do not use triggers, ad vehicle type field to your parent table and the child table and make them part of the foreign key.

Comment: do you mean like this? vehicle table: PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `vehicle_type`) and passenger_car table: FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id`, `vehicle_type`) REFERENCES vehicle (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: You need vehicle_type in the references part of the FK, otherwise yes, that's what I meant. See the main answer to the duplicate question for a lot more details on the theory behind this.